# PHPMyadmin Functions/Sotred Procedures Disapear

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

Bit of a strange issue

We can create functions and Stored procedures,  However as soon as the PHPMyadmin sesion ends,  the functions break.  They apear there in the list,  https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2zptz4z7qtgni8/Screenshot%202014-11-20%2016.42.10.png?dl=0

However Do not apear editable ( https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtkrew2coi3qg06/Screenshot%202014-11-20%2016.42.25.png?dl=0 )

and exporting it provides

```
Error in processing request: No routine with name `ao` found in database `table`
```

Any hints for debugging this one ?

Answer (score 0):

I logged into WHM as Root.  They where there and usable!   Escalated privileges for the procedures to all accounts.  and all was happy